# Ubuntu 18.04 Purpose Behind Splitting Analog/Digital Output, and How To Not Separate them?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

While my monitors show up correctly, my headset and any other speaker I connect seems to offer two audio outputs, Analog and Digital. I am not an audiophile, but they seem to offer the same sound quality, and lowering the Analog output lowers the maximum Digital output.

Is there any reason my devices show up like this? On Windows, they would show up as one device. I think this would be preferable, how would I enable that? Thanks.

Up-to-date Ubuntu 18.04
R7 1700 / GTX 1080 396.54
[image: View of Audio Output screen; PS4 shows as a speaker]

Answer (score 2):

Only those sound cards that offer both, an analog and a digital signal processing will appear as separate analog and digital devices.

In your case, if I read the data on your screeshot correctly, you connect your headset throught a PS4 controller. This controller can receive digital or analog audio signaly from the attached system.

You may prefer a digital sound processing whenever there is a high-end sound card attached where all desired sound processing and decoding will be done by this hardware. Analog output is reserved for those system that are only just able to playback or amplify the analog audio signal given. Since the PS4 controller can do both, you are free to choose whichever makes the best sound experience and lowest signal-noise ratio.

If you hear no difference you may prefer the digital sound processing of the controller to save some CPU power of your computer.